# store "N" number of records within an array of a fixed size

Tags: c#

Is it possible to store within an array a rolling set of values without exceeding the set index?

For example I put together a basic console example at as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] myvalue;
    myvalue = new int[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Array {0} is {1}", i, myvalue[i]);         
    }
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

In the current approach I get an index out of bounds exception. What I would like to do is to limit the array to 10 items but as the count increases overwrite the existing items with new values. Therefore I could iterate through 100 times but the array would only show the last ten values (89-99) at the end of the routine.

If an array is not the best approach I would welcome any suggestions as to how to store this in memory.

thank you

Comment: 89-99 is 11 values :p but how do you mean? overwrite thee existing items? show the lat ten? are you reading from or writing to the array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a List to store the values, then wrap the Add method to handle the limit on the number of items.  This would take care of all the "slide down" logic for you.

```
const int MAX_ITEMS = 10;
List<int> list = new List<int>();

void AddItem(int k)
{
    list.Add(k);
    if (list.Count > MAX_ITEMS)
    {
        // discard the item at the front of the list
        list.RemoveAt(0);
    }
}
```

Whenever you want to add a value, you just call `AddItem(n)`, for example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    AddItem(i);
}
```

Whenever you want to read out the values, you can simply do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(list[i]);
}
```

This also has the advantage that you can put less than the maximum number of items in (say you only have 6 instead of 10) and it will still work correctly (you don't have to worry about unfilled array items).

Answer (score 6):

Sounds to me like a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). There's an [existing implementation](http://circularbuffer.codeplex.com/) in C# on codeplex.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the array to always hold the last ten values *in the order they were encountered*, then you must "slide values down" the array each time by copying `array[N]` to `array[N-1]` for all N >= 1 and then writing the "latest" value at the last position.

If you don't need the array to have the values in this specific order, you can use the modulo trick and write to `array[i % ARRAYSIZE]` for any `i`; this will "loop over" to the beginning of the array as soon as you reach its end.

Finally, if want the values in order *and* you need a data structure that does not force you to copy over all elements on every iteration you can use:

- a [linked list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/he2s3bh7.aspx), if indexed access is not a requirement
- a double-ended queue (aka deque), if you also need indexed access -- .NET doesn't come with a built-in one, but there is a proven implementation as part of [PowerCollections](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than an array you could use a circular linked list.

In the snippet below the currentNode is always the last node entered.  This way as you go full circle by following the linked list you can make your list arbitrarily long and never have to worry where the end is because at some point you automatically start overwriting old values.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //create first node
    var firstNode = new Node();
    var lastNode = firstNode;

    //create linked list
    for(int i=0; i<9; i++)
    {
        var nextNode = new Node();
        lastNode.nextNode = nextNode;
        lastNode = nextNode;
    }

    //link tail of list to beginning to make the circular reference.
    lastNode.nextNode = firstNode;

    var currentNode = firstNode;

    //your code goes here
    for(int j=0; j<1000; j++)
    {
        currentNode.value = j; //now you set your values in your loop
        currentNode = currentNode.nextNode; //and move on to the next node
    }
}

public class Node
{
    public int value;
    public Node nextNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this:

```
myvalue = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    myvalue[i % myvalue.Length] = i;
```

Of course that will start from the beginning when reaching the end, so the array might not be in the order you wrote your values into it, but somewhat rotated. If you want to avoid that you need to copy the elements from `myvalue[1]` to `myvalue[myvalue.Length-1]` into `myvalue[1]` to `myvalue[myvalue.Length-2]` and overwrite `myvalue[myvalue.Length-1]` each time you insert a new element. Or you could rotate the array to fix the positioning after doing all insertions.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant code ever, but it illustrates how to make a circular buffer that records the n most recent values:

```
const int SIZE = 10;
int[] myValue = new int[SIZE];
int start = 0;
int count = 0;

void NewValue(int v)
{
    myValue[start] = v;
    if (count < SIZE)
        count++;
    start = (++start) % SIZE;
}

void ListValues()
{
    for (int i = start - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        Console.WriteLine(myValue[i]);
    if (count >= SIZE)
        for (int i = SIZE - 1; i >= start; i--)
            Console.WriteLine(myValue[i]);
    Console.WriteLine();
}

private void Test()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        NewValue(i);
        ListValues();
    }
}
```